# Rearranging data in file with awk

Tags: awk

I have a table

```
 ID   Comment    Statement
  1    hi         hello
  2    hi         hello
  1    cya        bye
  1    k          ok
  2    kk         ok
```

How would one go about producing a result like the following, using awk?  So the ID becomes the attribute, and it maintains the same order as the statement.

```
 1       2
 hi      hi
 cya     N/A
 k       kk
```

Answer (score 1):

This produces your desired output

```
awk '
  NR>1 {
    ids[$1]
    if (s!=$3) c++
    statements[c]=$3
    s=$3
    comments[$3,$1]=$2
  } 
  END {
    for (id in ids)
      printf "%s\t", id
    print ""
    for (i=1; i<=c; i++) {
      for (id in ids) {
        comment = (comments[statements[i],id] ? comments[statements[i],id] : "n/a")
        printf "%s\t", comment
      }
      print ""
    }
  }
' file
```

You have to remember a few things to maintain the order.

Comment: thankyou for your response.  however it seems to have an error. "illegal reference to array comment" on line 14 and 15

Comment: I added parentheses for the assignment to "comment" -- does that help?

Comment: no. still the same error

Comment: what OS? what version of awk?

Comment: Linux. and 1.3.3

Comment: Do you have `gawk` available? For me, I'm working with `GNU Awk 4.1.0`

Comment: yes, just installed

Comment: Should also work with `nawk`

Comment: having the same error :/

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'BEGIN { colwidth=8; format="%-" colwidth "s"; printf format "%s\n","1","2"; };
  NR==1 {next;};
  /^ *1/ { if (NR>2) print col2; col2="N/A"; printf format,$2; };
  /^ *2/ { col2=$2; };
  END { print col2;} ' file
1       2
hi      hi
cya     N/A
k       kk
```

Comment: Instead of building `format`, you can use `*` as the field width, and printf looks for the width value in the list of arguments: `printf "%-*s", colwidth, value`